# Speakers remapping for 7.1 or other systems, Windows and/or Linux

Tags: windows, linux, audio, gui, configuration-management

I'm currently trying to set up a custom 7.1 (almost that, it's only a 6.1) sound system, mixing different speakers connected to my mother board which is supposed to manage any normal 7.1 system.

Now I'm looking for a program that can remap any speaker connected to the computer. It can be on Windows or Linux, I use both of them.

The problem is that two of my pairs of speakers don't have a cable long enough to put one of the speaker to the left and the other one on the right. I'm forced to put the pairs on the same side. The computer thinks there's one on each side (for each pair of speakers) and it's impossible to tell to the sound chip that both speakers (from the same pair) are on the same side.

Does a program that can remap any speaker exist? (Linux and/or Windows compatible)

(By remapping, I mean telling to the sound chip "that speaker is that one and this one is another one".)

Comment: I suspect splitting the question into two different questions is a good idea. Also... maybe just get a longer cable? Audio extention cables do exist.

Comment: The cable goes from one speaker to the other one and is not unpluggable. The only way to get it longer would be to cut it and to weld it with another one. I don't have the spell to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Only thing that pops up into my mind is **Realtek HD Audio-Manager**. Though I believe, it's related to the motherboard/soundcard. But maybe you *can* install it on any system, not regarding hardware.

Anyways, this piece of software lets you do exactly what you're asking for. Every time you plug something into your motherboard, a window pops up, which asks you what type of speaker you just plugged in. This way you also don't need to care about the colors of the audio jacks, because you can simply assign it to the function you want.

[image: Realtek HD Audio-Manager]

I personally used this to solve a similar issue that the one you are facing now. I own a 2.1 Logitech system and wanted to turn it into a 4.1 system with my stereo. I just had to use the aux output of the stereo, put a *coaxial to audio jack* adapter on the other end and plugged it into my motherboard. The window popped up and I could assign the stereo as rear speakers. My self-made surround system so to speak.

Comment: Yup, I'm already using this one but it seems like that function doesn't work.The only plug that pops up a window for remapping is the main green one. Another thing is that I have a black version of this software. I've no clue if it is a newer version or anything. As soon as I'm back home, I'll try to find the same version as yours and check if that works.